# Convert a List<List<Long,Float,Float,Integer,Integer>> to Array<StructType> in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I would like to convert a String that represents a `List<List<Long,Float,Float,Integer,Integer>>` in an Array.
In order to achieve this, I use a UDF function with the following structure:

An example of the String is `[[337, -115.0, -17.5, 6225, 189],[85075, -112.0, -12.5, 6225, 359]]`

```
    def convertToListOfListComplex(ListOfList: String, regex: String): Array[StructType]
  ={
    val notBracket = ListOfList.dropRight(1).drop(1)
    val SplitString = notBracket.split("]").map(x=>if (x.startsWith("[")) x.drop(1) else x.drop(2))
    SplitString(0).replaceAll("\\s", "")

    val result =SplitString map {
      case s => {
        val split = s.replaceAll("\\s", "").trim.split(",")
        case class Row(a: Long, b: Float, c: Float, d: Int, e: Int)
        val element = Row(split(0).toLong, split(1).toFloat, split(2).toFloat, split(3).toInt, split(4).toInt)
        val schema = `valid code to transform to case class to StructType`
      }
    }
    return result
  }
```

I am using Spark 2.2.
I have tried different solution but I have found problems to obtain an Array of StructTypes, I obtain compilation errors or executions fails. Any suggestion??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing purpose, I created a test dataframe with the string mentioned in the question as

```
val df = Seq(
  Tuple1("[[337, -115.0, -17.5, 6225, 189],[85075, -112.0, -12.5, 6225, 359]]")
).toDF("col")
```

which is

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[337, -115.0, -17.5, 6225, 189],[85075, -112.0, -12.5, 6225, 359]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- col: string (nullable = true)
```

The `udf` function should be as following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def convertToListOfListComplex = udf((ListOfList: String) => {
  ListOfList.split("],\\[")
    .map(x => x.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]", "").split(","))
    .map(splitted => rowTest(splitted(0).trim.toLong, splitted(1).trim.toFloat, splitted(2).trim.toFloat, splitted(3).trim.toInt, splitted(4).trim.toInt))
})
```

where `rowTest` is a `case class` **defined outside the scope** as

```
case class rowTest(a: Long, b: Float, c: Float, d: Int, e: Int)
```

And calling the `udf` function

```
df.withColumn("converted", convertToListOfListComplex(col("col")))
```

should give you output as

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                |converted                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[337, -115.0, -17.5, 6225, 189],[85075, -112.0, -12.5, 6225, 359]]|[[337, -115.0, -17.5, 6225, 189], [85075, -112.0, -12.5, 6225, 359]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+


root
 |-- col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- converted: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- b: float (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- c: float (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- d: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- e: integer (nullable = false)
```

**To be on a more safe side** you can use `Try/getOrElse` in the `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def convertToListOfListComplex = udf((ListOfList: String) => {
  ListOfList.split("],\\[")
    .map(x => x.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]", "").split(","))
    .map(splitted => rowTest(Try(splitted(0).trim.toLong).getOrElse(0L), Try(splitted(1).trim.toFloat).getOrElse(0F), Try(splitted(2).trim.toFloat).getOrElse(0F), Try(splitted(3).trim.toInt).getOrElse(0), Try(splitted(4).trim.toInt).getOrElse(0)))
})
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: i think you forgot to save the transformation. so can I see the steps after the udf call and how you are saving to parquet?